# JSON response to database

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, upload

I am implementing uploads.im api on my site. It works well and images gets uploaded, but I get a JSON response like..

`{"status_code":200,"status_txt":"OK","data":{"img_name":"8zN9G.jpg","img_url":"http:\/\/s1.uploads.im\/8zN9G.jpg","img_view":"http:\/\/uploads.im\/8zN9G.jpg","img_width":"954","img_height":"1421","img_attr":"width=\"954\" height=\"1421\"","img_size":"327.8 KB","img_bytes":335711,"thumb_url":"http:\/\/s1.uploads.im\/t\/8zN9G.jpg","thumb_width":360,"thumb_height":536,"source":"base64 image string","resized":"0","delete_key":"8c9bd7ab84a7bd6f"}}`

and dont know how to parse this data to database. I want to insert in my database the url of uploaded image. please help me.

Comment: Please provide some information about what you have tried, or at the very least in which context. For instance, it is not clear if you want to process this JSON code with PHP (which I can only guess based on the tag).

Answer (score 1):

you can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$response = '{"status_code":200,"status_txt":"OK","data":{"img_name":"8zN9G.jpg","img_url":"http:\/\/s1.uploads.im\/8zN9G.jpg","img_view":"http:\/\/uploads.im\/8zN9G.jpg","img_width":"954","img_height":"1421","img_attr":"width=\"954\" height=\"1421\"","img_size":"327.8 KB","img_bytes":335711,"thumb_url":"http:\/\/s1.uploads.im\/t\/8zN9G.jpg","thumb_width":360,"thumb_height":536,"source":"base64 image string","resized":"0","delete_key":"8c9bd7ab84a7bd6f"}}';

$arr = json_decode($response, true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo $arr['data']['img_url'];
```

**OUPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [status_code] => 200
    [status_txt] => OK
    [data] => Array
        (
            [img_name] => 8zN9G.jpg
            [img_url] => http://s1.uploads.im/8zN9G.jpg
            [img_view] => http://uploads.im/8zN9G.jpg
            [img_width] => 954
            [img_height] => 1421
            [img_attr] => width="954" height="1421"
            [img_size] => 327.8 KB
            [img_bytes] => 335711
            [thumb_url] => http://s1.uploads.im/t/8zN9G.jpg
            [thumb_width] => 360
            [thumb_height] => 536
            [source] => base64 image string
            [resized] => 0
            [delete_key] => 8c9bd7ab84a7bd6f
        )

)
http://s1.uploads.im/8zN9G.jpg
```